executing job disabling through groovy
I have the following grrovy script that works perfectly fine in jenkins 2.249.3
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
Jenkins.instance.getItem("JobToBeDisabled").disable()

Whereas, when the same tried on jenkins 2.452.2 , I am hitting the error.
Building in workspace /var/jenkin_8080_home/jobs/JobToBeDisabled/workspace
[workspace] $ groovy /var/jenkin_8080_home/jobs/JobToBeDisabled/workspace/hudson52599949595130215.groovy
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "groovy" (in directory "/var/jenkin_8080_home/jobs/JobToBeDisabled/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:994)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:506)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:517)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.Groovy.perform(Groovy.java:106)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1894)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 16 more
Build step 'Execute Groovy script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Is there some syntax or variable declaration I am missing out ?

The issue is fixed.
The earlier code works as well. I mistakenly ran the code in "Execute Groovy script" instead of  "Execute system Groovy script"
Now, I will try to understand further on the difference between groovy and system groovy.

Jenkins itself is scripted with groovy and therefor is able to run groovy scripts (sometimes sandboxed, etc). Your error suggested, that the actual command line tool "groovy" would have been ran (which needs to be installed).

In my organization we use such syntax
Jenkins.instance.getItem("jobName").setDisabled(true)

Please try if this helps. Because there might be a problem with the groovy binary.
